# Does $\int_{-x}^{x}f(t)dt=0$ implies $f$ to be an odd function?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I know that for $\quad f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\quad$ continuous,     $$\int_{-x}^{x}f(t)dt=0 \quad \text{for all } x \in \mathbb{R} \implies f(-x)=-f(x) \quad \text{for all } x \in \mathbb{R}.$$
But is the above true for general function on $\mathbb{R}$? More precisely is the following true:
**Question:** For any Riemann integrable function $\quad f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $$\int_{-x}^{x}f(t)dt=0 \quad \forall \quad x\in \mathbb{R} \implies f(-x)=-f(x) \quad \forall \quad x\in \mathbb{R}.$$
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It's "almost true". Such a function differs from an odd function only on a null set.

Comment: It does not make sense, you can't have both $x$ in limits and inside the integral $dx$. Maybe you mean $\int_{-x_0}^{x_0}f(x)dx=0, \forall x_0\in \mathbb R$

Comment: @DanielFischer, Thanks. I've got you now. All we need to prove your statement is that the set of discontinuity of a Riemann Integrable function is null. So, on the complement of this null set, we can apply fundamental theorem of calculus to get the result.

Comment: You should replace "general function" by "Riemann integrable function" or even go to Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: @zhw. Thanks. I meant "Riemann integrable function". Edited now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can take an integrable odd function and change its value at a point $x > 0$ so that it's no longer odd but still satisfies all the integral conditions.

Answer (score 7):

This is not true in general.  Consider the function
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
1&:&x=1\\0&:&\text{otherwise}\end{array}\right.$$
Then $\int_a^b f(x)\ dx=0$ for all $a\leq b$, but $f$ is not odd.

Answer (score 6):

Let $ f $ be continuous.

Since
$$\int_{-x}^{x}f(t)dt=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt-\int_{0}^{-x}f(t)dt=0,$$
thus,

$$\dfrac{{\rm d}\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt}{{\rm d} x}-\dfrac{{\rm d}\int_{0}^{-x}f(t)dt}{{\rm d} x}=0,$$

namely, $$f(x)+f(-x)=0,$$
which is desired.

But, if we cancel the continuity, then the statement does not hold any more, since we can always redefine $f(-x_0)$ at an isolated point $-x_0$ such that $f(-x_0) \neq f(x_0)$, even though the integral keeps the same value.

Comment: The best answer imo. It doesn’t just answer the question and call it a day. +1